# MySQL - Join Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider I'm having 4 tables in my Database : 
Team, Player, Training and Team_player

A team can have multiple players.
A player has only one team.

A player can have multiple trainings.

I want to get all the player informations, with the date or their next training.
Next training is next date that is after current date.
Some players don't have a next training date but I still want their informations.

Here are the tables :

```
--Team--

| id_team | name |
|----------|------|
| 1        | Tata |
| 2        | Fifi |
| 3        | Fofo |

--Player--

| id_player | name | age |
|------------|------|-----|
| 1          | Jon  | 32  |
| 2          | Jim  | 21  |
| 3          | Andy | 20  |

-- Team_Player--

| id_team | id_player |
|----------|------------|
| 1        | 1          |
| 2        | 2          |
| 3        | 3          |

-- Training --

| id_training | id_player | start_date  |
|--------------|------------|--------------|
| 1            | 1          | 2020-01-12 |
| 2            | 1          | 2019-12-25 |
| 3            | 2          | 2014-05-12 |
| 4            | 3          | 2020-05-03 |
```

Here is what I want :

```
| id_team | id_player | id_training | player.name | age | start_date  |
|----------|------------|--------------|--------------|-----|--------------|
| 1        | 1          | 2            | Jon          | 32  | 2019-12-25 |
| 2        | 2          | NULL         | Jim          | 21  | NULL         |
| 3        | 3          | 4            | Andy         | 20  | 2020-05-03 |
```

I tried different things, LEFT JOINS, conditions... I made some search but I didn't find an answer for my case.
Here is an example :

```
SELECT training.start_date, player.name, training.id_training, team.id_team, player.age, player.id_player
FROM player
INNER JOIN player_team ON player_team.id_player = player.id_player
INNER JOIN team ON team.id_team = player_team.id_team
LEFT JOIN training ON training.id_player = player.id_player
WHERE training.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY player.id_player
```

But this is not what I want because if a player doesn't have a next training, I don't get any information about him.

Comment: `WHERE training.start_date > CURRENT_DATE` turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (`training.start_date` can be `NULL`, which is not `> CURRENT_DATE`). One solution would be to use this condition in the join, rather than in the `WHERE`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN training ON training.id_player = player.id_player
AND  training.start_date > CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: Also, why are you using a `GROUP BY` when you are not using an aggregation function (`sum`, `max` etc)?

Comment: Well you request Date to be bigger than a certain date. If it is null, you won’t get it. Try = NULL aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the condition for left joined  table to the related  ON clause

```
SELECT training.start_date
  , player.name
  , training.id_training
  , team.id_team
  , player.age
  , player.id_player
FROM player
INNER JOIN player_team ON player_team.id_player = player.id_player
INNER JOIN team ON team.id_team = player_team.id_team
LEFT JOIN training ON training.id_player = player.id_player
  AND  training.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
```

if you add the condition related  to left join tables in where clause this work as an inner join

If you want avoid duplicated  rows and not are using aggreagtion function youn should use distinct  clause

Answer (score 2):

You have the `LEFT JOIN` backwards, the `player` table needs to be on the `LEFT` side:

```sql
    SELECT training.start_date, player.name, training.id_training, team.id_team,     player.age, player.id_player
    FROM player
    INNER JOIN player_team ON player_team.id_player = player.id_player
    INNER JOIN team ON team.id_team = player_team.id_team
    LEFT JOIN training ON player.id_player = training.id_player
    WHERE training.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY player.id_player
```

This answer is *only* dealing with the specific issue you indicated:

> But this is not what I want because if a player doesn't have a next
>   training, I don't get any information about him.

Others have good suggestions regarding other possible issues.